# Laragon not start Apache service

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I was trying start apache service in Laragon, but launch the next alert:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of C:/laragon/etc/apache2/fcgid.conf: Wrapper C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.1.10/php-cgi.exe cannot be accessed: (720002) the system can not find the specify archive

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)